# Entity framework 5 spatial query

Tags: entity-framework-5, spatial

I'm using Entity Framework 5 Code First and have a database with location (DbGeography) of some persons.
The database also contains a list of objects with a location (also DbGeography of course).
The object entity as a NearestPerson property and a NearestPersonDistance property - neither of them are mapped in EF.

I would like to make the following query:
"Return all objects with the nearest person and the distance to the nearest person"

I would like to write a LINQ expression to do the query and would like help to do so.

Is it a bad approach to use a LINQ query for this or would you prefer to write a view or stored procedure instead?

Comment: Not any help on this? Please let me know if it needs more clarification or if I'm way off track